# How to resolve Cloudflare DNS Error 526 on Heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku, cloudflare

I have a web application running on Heroku that is experiencing some unusual behaviour. My DNS is CloudFlare and I'm running CloudFlare SSL certification that is Manually added to Heroku.

The problem is subtle at first. It looks like when I visit the root domain youworkremotely.com on a new browser or device I initially get an Error 526. However, If I subsequently visit www.youworkremotely.com I am able to enter the site and proceed as normal. The odd behaviour begins when I attempt to revisit the root domain youworkremotely.com I no longer see the Error 526 and it is redirected to www.youworkremotely.com.

Any of you guys/girls understand what is happening and can help me fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.

Initially the A record still pointed to the old IP address from the previous DNS provider but the CNAME record pointed to the correct heroku DNS URL. Updating the A record to the heroku provided DNS URL resolved the issue.